# WSO2 IE 6.3.0: Issue changing H2 to MySQL

Tags: wso2

I am new to WSO2 and have been investigating on installing the product and testing it. I have installed the latest WSO2 IE 6.3.0 on my win 10. Now, I was changing the default database of carbon from H2 to MySQL and this is where I am getting issue and need help.

I have followed the instructions as per https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Changing+to+MySQL i.e

1. Installed the mysql 5.7.23 on localhost
2. Created regdb database and regadmin user and assign privileges.
3. Changed the master-database.xml file under

   - C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\conf\datasources and
   - C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\wso2\analytics\conf\datasources

As below

```
    <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
    <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
    <jndiConfig>
        <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
    </jndiConfig>
    <definition type="RDBMS">
        <configuration>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/regdb</url>
            <username>regadmin</username>
            <password>regadmin</password>
            <driverClassName>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driverClassName>
```

Not changed registry.xml and user-mgt.xml as did not changed the datasource name.

Now, while starting the product for the first time with below command, it gives error for admin user.

```
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
```

Full error below:

```
C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\wso2\analytics\bin>wso2server.bat -Dsetup
JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181
CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\ENTERP~1\63AA0C~1.0\wso2\ANALYT~1\bin\..
Loading spark environment variables
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,028] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,028] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Windows 10 10.0, amd64
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,043] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\jre
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,043] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.8.0_181
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,043] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.181-b13,Oracle Corporation
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,043] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\ENTERP~1\63AA0C~1.0\wso2\ANALYT~1\bin\..
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,043] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : C:\PROGRA~1\WSO2\ENTERP~1\63AA0C~1.0\wso2\ANALYT~1\bin\..\tmp
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,043] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : Thapa, en-US, Europe/Berlin
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,304] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS} -  Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2018-08-29 14:15:36,460] [EI-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.template.manager.core.internal.ds.TemplateDeployerServiceTrackerDS} -  Successfully deployed the execution manager tracker service
[2018-08-29 14:15:40,945] [EI-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} -  nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:401)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:222)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:264)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:702)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:683)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:390)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1176)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:559)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:544)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:457)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:243)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:438)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:355)
        ... 22 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:5821)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:299)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.<init>(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:238)
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while persisting user : admin
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.persistUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1414)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.doAddUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1272)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:5815)
        ... 29 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error occurred while updating string values to database.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.updateStringValuesToDatabase(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:2432)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager.persistUser(JDBCUserStoreManager.java:1318)
        ... 31 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'UM_CHANGED_TIME' at row 1
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2868)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1573)
```

As, I am very much new to WSO2, can you please point me, as what is wrong or if, I have missed anything ?

Also, in their document link above, it says directory as ../repository/conf, but I don't have this repository directory under HOME. I am attaching a file with tree directory structure.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yenvx.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you able to set up the drivers for MySQL?

Download the relevant MySQL Java connector JAR file, and copy it to the /repository/components/lib/ directory.

You can refer the https://docs.wso2.com/display/ADMIN44x/Setting+up+MySQL for more details.

If you are using MySQL 5.7, when executing the following step to create db tables please make sure to use the correct db script.

mysql -u regadmin -p -Dregdb < 'PRODUCT_HOME/dbscripts/mysql5.7.sql';

Thanks

Comment: Thank you Viraj, Yes, mysql-connector-java-5.1.47.jar is already copied to C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\lib directory and have run mysql5.7.sql file. Is this the correct folder to copy it ?

Comment: yes, it is correct. 
If you are creating db tables using -Dsetup command when starting the server, it will pick the mysql.sql script as the default script to create db tables. Hence it may not pick the mysql5.7.sql script as the default script.
Therefore you can remove(backup somewhere) existing mysql.sql dbscript and rename mysql5.7.sql dbscript as mysql.sql and then start the server with -Dsetup.

Comment: Or you can create a new db and source the mysql5.7.sql script as follows and start the server without -Dsetup. When sourcing the script see if there are any errors in mysql console.

mysql> source <path to the script>\mysql5.7.sql; 

Thanks

Comment: Thank again @Viraj Hasith , I tried again, by moving script mysql5.7 to mysql.sql and then running with -Dsetup, It does creates the tables, but also throws the error:  

Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user has not been created. Error occurs while creating Admin user in primary user store.
        ... 27 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error while persisting user : admin

I have already tried running the script mysql5.7 manually as well, it works fine, but while starting the service, it gives same original error.

Comment: I configured and checked with EI 6.2.0 with MySQL 5.7.23 in windows 10 and worked fine. It should be the same as EI 6.3.0. 

Steps followed.....
1. Create a db, user, and grant privileges.
2. run the mysql5.7 script in the selected database.
3. Configure master-datasource file in the conf directory. (didn't configure analytics) 
4. Copy the connector jar file 
5. Start the server without -Dsetup

However, please check in the database UM_USER and UM_SYSTEM_USER tables having data or not.
It should be filled with data when server startup

Comment: Thanks @Viraj Hasith   I will re-install EI again and will retry as above. One question on this. which command you use to start your server and from which directory ?

Comment: Hi @Viraj Hasith Just to update that, I downloaded EI 6.2.0 now. Followed the process as you mentioned and was able to change the carbon database to Mysql. Not sure, why it was not working with 6.3. There are some mysql ssl error, but I will figure that out. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you ran the DB script for MySQL? The script creates tables on the DB, once that is done then you can connect to the DB by configuring it in `masterdatasource.xml`, the DB scripts for different DB can be found under the folder `dbscripts`

Comment: Thanks @amg_amit, Yes, I had run the script as below.

mysql> use regdb
Database changed
mysql> source C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\dbscripts\mysql5.7.sql
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)
...............

Also, I don't see wso2server.bat under C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\bin but only under C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\wso2\analytics\bin or C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.3.0\wso2\broker\bin directories.
Their document is very confusing with different directory structure then the install.

Comment: Are the tables created in DB?